# No Bootable device issue after Installing Kali Linux - Acer Aspire ES1-533

Tags: kali-linux, uefi, acer

I have purchased 3 Acer Aspire ES1-533 Laptos , I just tried to install Kali linux , created bootable disk using Rufus , and it was a GPT/UEFI compatible USB drive. But after my installation the system shows no bootable device found. Please help me to fix this. In bios there is no option for changing UEFI boot type. I have tried many options which are available in the internet. Contacted Acer customer support they simply neglected , by saying we are not supporting Linux Tried many ways, dome morethan 10 times installation some technicians told me to update BIOS from 1.08 to another version But updating BIOS will affect the performance of PC

I have posted in kali forum and tried all steps they have told, but not working [**[LINK To KALI](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?38258-No-Bootable-device-issue-after-Installing-Kali-Linux-Acer-Aspire-ES1-533)** ]

Friends I have no life without Kali...

Comment: We can't help with what you've told us. You need to collect all the information from your thread on the kali forums and add it to your question. However, seeing the questions you've asked there, I would urge you to forget about Kali and use a normal distribution. Kali is a tool for experts and isn't supposed to be used as a regular OS for users.

Comment: Whoever told you that updating BIOS will affect the performance, he told you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system using a live Linux disk of either Kali Linux or Ubuntu. Open a terminal and `chroot` into Kali Linux installation directory and reinstall `grub`. Please read online for `grub` reinstallation procedure. Make sure you're installing the `grub` bootloader for `UFI` based system.